# Selecting text (visibly) when button is clicked in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I would like to select all the text in a contenteditable div when a button is clicked. Kind of like

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").select()
```

I've looked into creating a range but that isn't visible to the user.

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript (using closure library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I did not understand what do you want

```
function highlight(element){
      var inner = document.getElementById(element).innerText;
      inner = "<span class=\"highlighted\">" + inner + "</span>"
    }
    <style>
      span .highlighted{
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    <style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used css to highlight the text since I was unable to find something that could. Maybe closure library editor would work but have solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerText;
```

this line to get the content of any thing has an id

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerText =  x;
```

this line to set the content

now put that code in a function  and call it onClick like this

```
<input type="submit" onClick="functionname();" id="submit">
```

Comment: Was going trough my questions to see if I had any that needs selecting the right answer. innerText isn't supported by many browsers and some that do will give you the .textContent (this will not give you the whitespace correctly). I was looking to highlight the text only when a button was clicked. Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply.